# Taking $4$ shots or $6$?

Tags: probability

> Suppose your skill (the ability to make a shot) follows a binomial distribution (with some unknown $p$). You need to make at least half of the shots. Would you rather take $4$ or $6$? More precisely, what should be the $p$ which is the threshold of your decision?

**My Try:** assuming $0 < p < 1$.
$${{6}\choose{3}}p^3(1-p)^3 ={{4}\choose{2}}p^2(1-p)^2 \\
\implies p(1-p) = 6/20
$$

but apparently the answer is: $3/5$.

What's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: The question says AT LEAST half of the shots. Your probabilities are for EXACTLY $3$ and $2$ shots.

Comment: Oh okay. By the way, how should *this* result be interpreted (= at least half)? There's no such $p$?

Comment: If you make $6$ shots at least half means "$3$ or more". That is, $3,4,5$ or $6.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of $B(6,p)$ we fail with probability ($0,1,2$ shots)

$$(1-p)^6+6p(1-p)^5+15p^2(1-p)^4.$$

In the case of $B(4,p)$ we fail with probability ($0,1$ shots)

$$(1-p)^4+4p(1-p)^3.$$

Now, we have

$$(1-p)^4+4p(1-p)^3-(1-p)^6-6p(1-p)^5-15p^2(1-p)^4=2p^2(1-p)^3(5p-3). $$ And thus we get $p=\dfrac{3}{5}.$

We can conclude that if $p<\dfrac{3}{5}$ it is better to choose $6$ shots and if $p>\dfrac{3}{5}$ $4$ shots.

Comment: Thank you mfl!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of making AT LEAST half shots out of 6 is

$$
\binom{6}{3}p^3(1-p)^3 +\binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2 +\binom{6}{5}p^5(1-p) +\binom{6}{6}p^3 
$$

and for making at least 2 out of 4 is

$$
\binom{4}{2}p^2(1-p)^2 +\binom{4}{3}p^3(1-p) +\binom{4}{4}p^4
$$

For threshold $p$, equating both, we get:
$$
10p^4-36p^3+48p^2-28p+6 = 0
$$
which reduces to 
$$
2(x-1)^3(5x-3) = 0
$$
which gives $p = {\frac 35}$ since $0 \lt p \lt 1$.

Comment: you have a power of $p$ in your third equation which I am sure is not intentionally ;)

Comment: @Jan fixed. Thanks